# How to maintain culture through session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a multilingual web-forms web application which I am using resource files and a BasePage class which sets the culture based on the QueryString that was included in the page which is inheriting from this class. This is all working well, if a tad clunky as I am having to do this sort of thing for every button which takes the user to a different page to maintain the culture:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "cy-GB")
{
    return "~/Secure/Details.aspx?lang=cy-GB&PersonId=" + currentPersonId;
}
else
{
    return "~/Secure/Details.aspx?PersonId=" + currentPersonId;  
}
```

I knew there was probably a better way of doing this but being a novice as it worked I simply made do.

This was until I had to implement an `asp:SiteMapPath` control. I initially assumed that I could simply create a resource entry for the `url` property like I had done for the `title`:

```
<siteMapNode 
    title="$resources:SiteMapLocalizations,HomePageTitle" 
    description="Home" 
    url="~$resources:SiteMapLocalizations,HomePageUrl">
```

However this resulted in a server error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

I've done some reading and I believe I need to somehow store the current culture to a session variable which will follow the user around so when they click 'Home' on the breadcrumb it will be consistent with the culture and grab the appropriate text from the resource files, I'm also hoping this will allow me to remove all of the `IF ELSE` statements I've had to write to maintain the current language throughout the application.

My question is however, where do I start with this, I cannot find any guide step by step to follow in order to achieve this, can anyone provide some instructions?

Comment: Look at the documentation for Page.InitializeCulture, and the "How to" articles linked from that page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a button of some sort which triggers the change of language. In my case I have two versions of the header, one with an English link which will append the Query String to English and one for Welsh, something like:

**ASP**

```
<a id="languagelink" runat="server" title="Cymraeg">Cymraeg</a>
```

**C#**

```
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() == "en-GB")
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(currentPage);
        languagelink.HRef = String.Format(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)+"?lang=cy-GB");         
    }
```

Every page which requires the language switch needs to inherit from my custom `BasePage` like so:

**Inheritance**

```
public partial class Secure_CustomerSummary : BasePage
```

**Base_Page**

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            if (Session["language"] == null)
            {
                Session["language"] = "en-GB";
            }

            else
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["lang"] == null)
                {
                    SetSessionCulture();
                }

                if (Request.QueryString["lang"] != null)
                {
                    string qs = Request.QueryString["lang"];
                    Session["language"] = qs;
                }

                SetSessionCulture();
            }

            SetSessionCulture();           
        }

        private void SetSessionCulture()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["language"].ToString());
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["language"].ToString());
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
    }
```